# Map fragment is not hidden when switch between fragments Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to switch between fragments using a bottom navigation. However, if I switch to other fragments from the map fragment, the map fragment is still in the background while other fragment is being shown on the front.

[image]

[image]

Please see my code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment messageFragment = new MessageFragment();
    private Fragment mapFragment = new MapsFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, mapFragment, null).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, messageFragment, null).commit();
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        //bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.mapsFragment);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.mapsFragment:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(messageFragment).show(mapFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.messageFragment:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mapFragment).show(messageFragment).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the XML for both the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Problem**

You are adding both fragments to the same container, `R.id.hostFragment`.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, mapFragment, null).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, messageFragment, null).commit();
```

Per the documentation for [hide](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#hide(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) and [show](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#show(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)), this means that you are hiding and then showing the same *container*.

**A Solution**

Use two different container views:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mapContainer, mapFragment, null).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.messageContainer, messageFragment, null).commit();
```

**Another Solution**

Use [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) instead of hiding and showing.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, mapFragment, null).commit();
// Don't add this in `onCreate`
// fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.hostFragment, messageFragment, null).commit();

...

    // Replace the fragment currently being displayed
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mapsFragment:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hostFragment, mapFragment).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.messageFragment:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hostFragment, messageFragment).commit();
            break;
    }
```